# PHP: Auto Generate Search Database

Tags: php, mysql, blogs, auto-generate, search-box

Hello I am currently making my own blog using a template. And I want to add to it as many features as I can. So, I decided to add a search box in my blog. I know we can create a search script using the mysql `LIKE` clause. But what I want to do is that create a php script that automatically scans my website for links and the it stores them in an array (optional: with their meta description and meta tags). And then I will create a `cron job` to run the script at given intervals.

Thanks, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: And what is your question/problem?

Comment: @EduardoVerdugoCáceres I want to know how to auto generate the links array with their meta description and tags.